# How to use Talend to read/write SAS files without installing a SAS server?

Tags: sas, talend

I'd like to use Talend to manipulate SAS files; however, the SAS plugins require some sort of server authentication. I don't have a SAS server on my machine and I'd like not to install one if possible. Is there a way to read/write SAS files without installing the server?

Answer (score 2):

Not easily!  The simplest way would be to purchase a copy of BASE SAS and use it as a local server - see thread below.

[How can I read a SAS dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374193/how-can-i-read-a-sas-dataset)

A cheaper way would be to purchase a licensed version of the WPS product:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Programming_System

A free, but less reliable way would be to use an open source reader, such as:

http://kasper.eobjects.org/2011/06/sassyreader-open-source-reader-of-sas.html

hope this helps.